# Exception in subscription terminates Observable in Angular but not in Node

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I have this example code sequence that I either run in Angular or in a node app. Behavior is different, and I would like to know why.

```
        of(1, 2, 3, 4).subscribe((x) => {
            console.log(`x: ${x}`);
            if (x === 2) {
                throw new Error('xxx');
            }
        });
```

When executing in node all four numbers are written to the console. Exception is shown afterwards.

When executing in Angular, e.g. in any ngOnInit(), it only logs 1 and 2 and then the Observable is terminated. The consequence is that any exception in a subscription block breaks the program.

Is there any description of why and how this difference in behavior.

**Addendum**: Reading more on the subject, the Angular (or more general the browser) behavior is what is to be expected. It is really the node.js behavior that is surprising. Why does the node.js program not stop after two digits?

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz

Comment: I hope this works. It's my first stackblitz sharing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqdjns?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Your stackblitz does show an exception, not the behavior you describe in your question.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you mean that you can't see an indication on your page that an exception happened, but that's expected, since you are not processing that exception into something that is displayed on the page. But the console does show the exception.

Comment: No, Aviad. What I mean is: When I execute the code in a plain *ts file using node.js, all four digits are printed. I wonder about the difference.

Comment: Actually, reading more on the documentation, the Angular behavior is what is to be expected. It is really the node.js behavior that is surprising.

Comment: I ran it on node, and i only get 1 and 2, and then an exception... whats your setup like? My node version is 14.17.0, using `"typescript": "^4.3.5"` and `"rxjs": "^6.6.7"` in my package.json

Comment: * node 14.16.1  
* typescript 4.3.2  
* rxjs 7.2.0

Comment: Indeed with your setup i get all 4 numbers!!!!

Comment: It's the rxjs version!

Comment: rxjs 7 is the culprit - I wonder if it's a bug or if it's a feature :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments section, you are actually trying to figure out the difference in behavior between the rxjs `v6 and v7` in terms of handling the `consumer thrown` unhandled errors.

In general throwing errors from the observers is a bad idea as it will lead to blocking of the observables if shared between `multiple` observers. This problem is handled in the `v6` by improving the error handling mechanism as mentioned here [`SafeSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.6.7/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L169) and more specifically in [`next`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.6.7/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L203). Below snapshot of the `next`

```
next(value?: T): void {
    if (!this.isStopped && this._next) {
      const { _parentSubscriber } = this;
      if (!config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling || !_parentSubscriber.syncErrorThrowable) {
        this.__tryOrUnsub(this._next, value);
      } else if (this.__tryOrSetError(_parentSubscriber, this._next, value)) {
        this.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
  }
```

If you see from the above snapshot when an unhandled error is thrown from the observer the code is trying to `subscribe` and then if error it is `unsubscribing` the observable in `__tryOrUnsub`. Finally the error is added to call stack and thrown once the call stack is empty from method  `hostReportError`(once all the observers complete `asynchronously`). Below is the sample stackblitz to demonstrate the same.

[`https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v7dojh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v7dojh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

This logic further changed in `v7` as mentioned by the this [`commit`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/54ace0b4bf255b72ba589fe74eaea52ca9d1800d#diff-f66f51cfa3d371eb91a4d6f6be963f6beb18ac30b421b8055f0e10474a7628da). The unsubscribing logic is removed and the `asynchronous` error call stack is maintained as shown below sample stackblitz, due to which the all the 4 elements are printed and the error is printed to console once the call stack is empty asynchronously usning `reportUnhandledError` -

[`https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p8zj2k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p8zj2k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)