# Different behavior version 6 and version 7. Is it intended?

Tags: rxjs

I have the below script that shows a significant difference between version 6.6.7 and version 7.2.0 of rxjs.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

of(1, 2, 3, 4).subscribe((x) => {
    console.log(`x: ${x}`);
    if (x === 2) {
        throw new Error('xxx');
    }
});
```

6.6.7 prints 1 and 2 but version 7.2.0 prints 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Is that intended? What is the background / reasoning?

Comment: For reference, here is the associated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqdjns. Change the rxjs version to 7.2 and see the difference.

Comment: Someone on twitter suggested that this may be related to this issue: https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/issues/5979

Comment: In this stackblitz rxjs ver is 7.2.0, and I see only "12".

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68533576/exception-in-subscription-terminates-observable-in-angular-but-not-in-node/68551100#68551100